# Check if there's a content type published

Tags: nodes, 6

How can I check (via PHP code) if a content type is published?

I have a content type called 'House' and a content type called 'People'. On the 'People' content type, there's a field called 'House'. If the user didn't publish a 'House' content type yet, I want to hide this field.

I thought I could do it by using a hook_form_alter, isn't it possible? If it is, I just don't know how to check if a content type was published or not. Something like: if (isset($node->type == 'House')) ... Of course it doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
hook_form_alter() {
  /* check that you're looking at the right form here.. */
    global $user;
    $type_to_check = 'House';

    $query = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node n JOIN users u ON n.uid = u.uid WHERE n.status = 1 AND u.uid = %d AND n.type = '%s'", $user->uid, $type_to_check);

    if(empty(db_result($query))) {
      /* kill the thing you don't want here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a template to your content type. In the respective new template of your content type, you can add the condition to do this:

```
if ($node->status == 1){
unset($node->your_field_name);//here, for example, the field name is 'your_field_name'
}
```

**note:** to create a new template to your content type, look inside your theme directory, and create a copy of file node template **node.tpl.php**, then rename this copy according your Content Type, for example, if machine name of your content type is my_content_type, then:

```
node-my_content_type.tpl.php
```

and then add the code indicated above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what I need. I'm gonna be more specific: I have a content type called 'House' and a content type called 'People'. On the People' content type, there's a field called 'House'. If the user didn't publish a content type 'House' yet, I want to hide this field. I thought I could do it using a custom module, is it possible? Something like:

if ($form_id == 'people_node_form') {

if (!isset($node->type == 'House')) {
$form['field_house']['#type'] = 'hidden';
}
}

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: you can build a custom module and then use hook form_alter() (here is one example of this hook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067782/drupal-form-alter) and review this documentation http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6

Comment: Yes, I'm using hook_form_alter. But I don't know how to check if a specific content type is published or not, inside the hook_form_alter. I was thinking about something like: if (!isset($node->type == 'House')), but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think that you can use $node->status

Comment: hello, I think that you can use $form_state['values']['status']

Comment: Still didn't work for me. I tried this:
/////
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'house_node_form') {

    if ($form_state['values']['status'] == 0) {
      dsm($form);
    }
    if ($form_state['values']['status'] == 1) {
      dsm($form_id);
    }
} ////
I tried with dsm just for testing. When there wasn't a content type 'House' created, it printed a dsm($form). Same when I created a content type 'House'...

Comment: when I view nodes: if ($node->status == 0){dsm("..something..")} did the work (you have a typo in your function, review brackets)

Comment: I think that I am in a confusion: seems that you want make modifications over node when is viewed (as first assumed). like an alternative to my first answer, I think that you can review hook_nodeapi() or hook_view().

Answer (score 0):

You have to query the nodes table for the uid of the current people node and type house. If you don't find a house unset the field in your hook_form_alter function.